# SWI Prolog editor fail to consult

Tags: swi-prolog

my swi prolog editor is not working correctly. Whenever i tried to consult a simple predicate, it will just return

consult('C:/Users/Huan/Desktop/'filename.pl').

By right it should prompt out the following message if the consult is successful : 
% library(win_menu) compiled into win_menu 0.00 sec, 20,952 bytes % library(swi_hooks) compiled into pce_swi_hooks ......... (etc, etc)

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

but am not even getting that. I i tried uninstalling both prolog and the editor, but still no luck.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I used SWI Prolog 32 bit on windows 7 32bits. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have a stray apostrophe in your input.  The `consult` predicate wants an atom, and `'C:/Users/Huan/Desktop/'filename.pl'` is not an atom.  I'd try

```
consult('filename.pl').
```

or

```
consult('Desktop/filename.pl').
```

or

```
consult('C:/Users/Huan/Desktop/filename.pl').
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As other answer, you have stray apostrophe. Anyway, forget consult. Just give this -

```
?- ['C:/Users/Huan/Desktop/filename']
```